# Mono.WebBrowser Winforms Linux

Tags: linux, winforms, mono, webkit

I'm trying to render a *IWebBrowser* in a *Windows.Forms.Panel* using *Mono.WebBrowser*.
I'm developing using Visual Studio 2013 and the application works fine in Windows. When I run the application under Mono in Fedora 21, everything works fine except for the browser, which is not rendered.
I also tried to develop directly in Linux MonoDevelop, but it seems that all solutions need Gtk library.
I'd like just to use *Windows.Forms* and all I read around is very OLD and sending me always here: 
http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/webbrowser/
where I read:

> The Mono.WebKit namespace provides a Gtk main loop so that WebKit can run in a Winforms application (which has no gtk main loop, obviously), and uses the webkit-sharp library.

I tried really everything I can found around, but it asks me to use Gtk on Linux or it asks for *libgluezilla* library which I read it's old and insecure (and I even cannot find how to install it in Fedora).
I evaluated also alternative solutions (*Awesomium*, etc) but they relies on Gtk too.
Any help/very simple example would be really appreciated. Thanks!